# assign ng-repeat value to style property

Tags: css, angularjs

I have an ng-repeater which successfully gets the values from the controller through an angular class. However I have a double value which I'm trying to assign to the styling of the div. 
Is it possible to assign a returned ng-repeat value to the style property of the div?

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="HomeController" ng-init="init()">
<pre>{{ClockLogic}}</pre>
<br />
<br />
<div id="containerDiv" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="clockDiv" style="width: 800px;" ng-repeat="clock in ClockLogic">
            <div class="row" id="clockwidget" style="background-color: "{{clock.LogicColor}};">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Angular:

```
 $scope.ClockLogic = [{
        LogicID: '',
        LogicClockWidth: '',
        LogicMaxWidth: '',
        LogicColor: ''
    }]

    $http.get('/Home/SetClockTimes')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.ClockLogic = response.data;
            console.log("status:" + response.status);
            console.log("data: " + $scope.ClockLogic);

        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.error('Error occurred:', response.status, response.data);
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log("Task Finished.");
        });
```

Can anyone help me out to set the background colour or the width based on the `{{clock}}` value?

Comment: See [AngularJS ng-style Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="HomeController" ng-init="init()">
<pre>{{ClockLogic}}</pre>
<br />
<br />
<div id="containerDiv" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="clockDiv" style="width: 800px;" ng-repeat="clock in ClockLogic">
            <div class="row" id="clockwidget" ng-style="{'background-color': clock.LogicColor}">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! That is EXACTLY what I needed. Appreciate the fast response and assistance.